# how would you find out what font this is?

Tags: fonts

help appreciated, don't have enough experience with fonts to get a good idea of how to copy one

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The image is too poor quality to match with any accuracy. Sorry. Only thing I can say is that it's a sans serif font.

Comment: See https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366 for general guidelines - but the chances are that's just far too blurred for anything to correctly recognise it. It could easily be Helvetica Neue - https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnwB1.png - but any subtlety is lost with that kind of zoom level, as different original font size & antialias algorithm could make all the difference to rendering/perception when zoomed.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer through the haze of font hinting, but it looks like Roboto or Arial. If you tell us where this image comes from, that would help us answer your question.